# Rails 5.2 primary and foreign keys are big ints now? What's the reason?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I see my migrated table look like this:

```
create_table "addresses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "habitat_id"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "state"
    t.string "zip"
    t.string "address"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["habitat_id"], name: "index_addresses_on_habitat_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_addresses_on_user_id"
  end
```

Where can I read about bigints and what the decision behind this was?

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/26266

Answer (score 0):

In smaller tables, the difference due to column width is negligible (in fact [it's been claimed](https://twitter.com/pvh/status/730153278680399872) that due to alignment, `integer` and `bigint` often use the same amount of disk space). In large tables, it's not rare to hit the 2 billion limit of an `integer` -- but switching the type of the primary key when you have 2 billion rows is.. not fun.

Thus: the smart default is to use the wider value.

You can find more discussion in [the merged PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/26266) and [its predecessor](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/24962).